# C++ what does the minimum size of integral value mean?

Tags: c++

[image]

Can someone tell what does this minimum size means? Does it mean? Int value can be at least 1 to 32bit, I mean 1 - 32 bit or more than 32 bit numbers are possible value for int? And what does this 6 significant digits mean?
I found this in C++ primer 5 th edition, Im a beginner and I heard this very good book for beginners

Comment: for the list of good books see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714). And please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714), it's difficult to see what you're talking about

Comment: The minimum size means that the size of the type must consist of at least as many bits in any given implementation of the language.

Comment: minimum size means that the size of that type must be at least that value in any implementations, and the real size can be larger. [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/995714)

Comment: And what does 6 significant digits mean?

Comment: It means that whatever encoding for floating point numbers is used, it must preserve 6 most significant digits (the rest of the digits may be subject to [rounding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1)).

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the concept of significant digits, try a math book or a search engine.